# Simple timepicker for a fragment activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-timepicker

### I am trying to launch a `timepicker` from a `edittext` in a fragment

**Buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu2.java**

```
public class Buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu2 extends Fragment implements PickTime{

    RadioGroup radioGroup;


    EditText ed1,ed2;
    boolean flag =false;
    TimePickerFragment newFragment;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu2, container, false);

        ed1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.from_lunch_edit_text_id);
        ed2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.to_lunch_edit_text_id);

        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);        

        newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();

        ed1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus){
                  flag =false;
                  newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
                }
               }
            });

        ed2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus){
                  flag =true;
                  newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
                }
               }
            });
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){  
          public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
             // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
                   if(checkedId == R.id.SelectDaysRG_ID)
                   {
                      view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_individualdays).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   }
                   else if(checkedId == R.id.WeekdaysRG_ID)
                   {
                       view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_individualdays).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                   }
                   else if(checkedId == R.id.WeekendsRG_ID)
                   {
                       view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_individualdays).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                   }

          }
        });


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void returnTime(String value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(flag==false)
        ed1.setText(value);
        else if(flag==true)
        ed2.setText(value);

    }



}
```

**TimePickerFragment.java**

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
    public interface PickTime
    {
        public void returnTime(String value);

    }

    PickTime mCallback;
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        mCallback = (PickTime) getActivity();
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user

        if(mCallback!=null)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(hourOfDay);
            sb.append(":");
            sb.append(minute);
            mCallback.returnTime(sb.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Log**::

```
12-27 08:55:53.543: E/AndroidRuntime(279): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-27 08:55:53.543: E/AndroidRuntime(279): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.project.findmybuffet.BuffetOfferings_MainFragmentActivity
12-27 08:55:53.543: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.project.findmybuffet.TimePickerFragment.onCreateDialog(TimePickerFragment.java:24)
12-27 08:55:53.543: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:295)
12-27 08:55:53.543: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
12-27 08:55:53.543: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
12-27 08:55:53.543: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
12-27 08:55:53.543: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
12-27 08:55:53.543: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
12-27 08:55:53.543: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-27 08:55:53.543: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-27 08:55:53.543: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-27 08:55:53.543: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-27 08:55:53.543: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-27 08:55:53.543: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-27 08:55:53.543: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-27 08:55:53.543: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-27 08:55:53.543: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

### {Edit} hosted fragment activity

**BuffetOfferings_MainFragmentActivity.java**

```
public class BuffetOfferings_MainFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    Button back_button;

    FragmentManager manager;
    FragmentTransaction transaction;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.buffet_offerings_fragment_main_reference);

        Buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu1 breakfast_fragment=new Buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu1();
        Buffet_offerings_lunch_menu1 lunch_fragment=new Buffet_offerings_lunch_menu1();
        Buffet_offerings_dinner_menu1 dinner_fragment=new Buffet_offerings_dinner_menu1();

        manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        transaction=manager.beginTransaction();

        transaction.add(R.id.BREAKFAST_LAYOUT_ID,breakfast_fragment, "breakfast_menu1_fragment");
        transaction.add(R.id.LUNCH_LAYOUT_ID,lunch_fragment, "lunch_menu1_fragment");
        transaction.add(R.id.DINNER_LAYOUT_ID,dinner_fragment, "dinner_menu1_fragment");

        transaction.commit();



        back_button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.TopNavigationBarRestaurantBuffetOfferingsBackButton);
        back_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();

            }
        });









    }

    public void BreakfastRedMenu1(View V){

        Buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu2  breakfast_fragment1=new Buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu2();
        transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.BREAKFAST_LAYOUT_ID, breakfast_fragment1, "Tag1");
        transaction.commit();

    }

    public void LunchRedMenu1(View V){

        Buffet_offerings_lunch_menu2  lunch_fragment1=new Buffet_offerings_lunch_menu2();
        transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.LUNCH_LAYOUT_ID, lunch_fragment1, "Tag2");
        transaction.commit();

    }

    public void DinnerRedMenu1(View V){

        Buffet_offerings_dinner_menu2  dinner_fragment1=new Buffet_offerings_dinner_menu2();
        transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.DINNER_LAYOUT_ID, dinner_fragment1, "Tag3");
        transaction.commit();

    }


    public void BreakfastGreenMenu2(View V){

        Buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu1  breakfast_fragment2=new Buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu1();
        transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.BREAKFAST_LAYOUT_ID, breakfast_fragment2, "Tag4");
        transaction.commit();

    }   

    public void LunchGreenMenu2(View V){

        Buffet_offerings_lunch_menu1  lunch_fragment2=new Buffet_offerings_lunch_menu1();
        transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.LUNCH_LAYOUT_ID, lunch_fragment2, "Tag5");
        transaction.commit();

    }

    public void DinnerGreenMenu2(View V){

        Buffet_offerings_dinner_menu1  dinner_fragment2=new Buffet_offerings_dinner_menu1();
        transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.DINNER_LAYOUT_ID, dinner_fragment2, "Tag6");
        transaction.commit();

    }


}
```

Comment: use `BuffetOfferings_MainFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity`.

Comment: `mCallback = (PickTime) getActivity();` why you are casting Activity to  `PickTime` ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K ..... How can i resolve this .... can u please give answer as your feedback ... im new to fragments ( I was able to execute this when i extended Fragment activity) ... now since i need to do these for fragment class .... i am not able to do

Comment: @Ketan ..... I am using fragments that is being launched from a activity that extends FragmentActivity ... so i am trying to implement here ... please post an answer for my  code

Comment: @smriti3 you need to communicate value to activity and then to fragment and your activity is to implement `implements PickTime{`

Comment: @smriti3 check this for more info http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html. Also has a example

Comment: @Raghunandan  .... can you please show me as the answer ... i am completely confused .... i did understand your last model i know how to do without fragment now ...but like this can you show with my code as your answer

Comment: @smriti3 fragment to fragment communication should be done through the hosting activity. Same answer iin your previous post. Use interface and get the value in activity and then pass the value to fragment

Comment: @Raghunandan .... i have posted the hosting activity for the fragment ... please see the edit

Comment: @smriti3 there is a example in the docs. pls check the same. and refer your previous answer

Comment: @smriti3 did you solve your problem??

Comment: @ Raghunandan .... I did try for interfargment communication between two fragments where date picker is not involved ..... but i am not able to implement this use case :(

Comment: @smriti3 check my post. i posted a example. Modify the same accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

You can interface as a call back to the activity. So get the time in activity and then communicate to fragment.

Example:

For the example sake i am extending Activity. You can extend FragmentAcitivty ans use support library and make proper imports.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements PickTime{

        EditFragment newFragment; 
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            newFragment = new EditFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment);
            //transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void returnTime(String value) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(newFragment.isVisible())
            {
                newFragment.setEdittextvalue(value);
            }

        }

    }
```

Fragment with just a Edittext

```
public class EditFragment extends Fragment {

    EditText ed;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout,container,false);

        return v;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ed = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        ed.setOnClickListener(new  OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              TimePickerFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
              newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
            }

        });
    }
    public void setEdittextvalue(String value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ed.setText(value);

    }
}
```

TimerPickerFragment

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mCallback = (PickTime) activity;
    }

    public interface PickTime
    {
        public void returnTime(String value);

    }

    PickTime mCallback;
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user

        if(mCallback!=null)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(hourOfDay);
            sb.append(":");
            sb.append(minute);
            mCallback.returnTime(sb.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect ... Thank you .... your guidance helped ! .... If these r any blogs that give explanation with example for this use case .... please share the links .. just for my learning ... :)

Comment: @smriti3 all you need to do is read the docs has enough info.

Comment: @ Raghunandan .... its a 24hr format say now the time is 4:30 PM i think it will display as 16:30 .... what changes we need to make if we want the value to be set as 4:30PM (12 hour format)... can you make a edit in TimerPickerFragment.java

Comment: but whatever it is you should see it in the log atleast the value first

Comment: I tried to modify the code DateFormat.is24HourFormat .... to .....DateFormat.is12HourFormat ..... but its not happening ... what minor changes should be made ?

Answer (score 1):

initialize mCallback in Buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu2 like this

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mCallback = (PickTime) activity;
}
```

Comment: can u please post Buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu2.java & TimePickerFragment.java editing with your answer ... i dont know which other components i need to move