# simple Timepicker for fragment not setting the value to edittext

Tags: android, android-fragments

### [I am referring to my previous question that involves launching a timepicker from fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20795329/2901850)

- I did successfully implement in the project but
- I am able to make the `timepicker` pop-up but when i click set on the
  `timepicker` i cannot see the values on the `edittext`, it empty
- So even though `timepicker` pops value is not been st in `edittext`
- Where am i doing wrong

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements PickTime{

    Fragment1 newFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        newFragment=new Fragment1();
        FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(newFragment, "Fragment-Tag");
        transaction.commit();
    }

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
         return true;
     }


    @Override
    public void returnTime(String value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(newFragment.isVisible())
        {
            newFragment.setEdittextvalue(value);
        }
    }


}
```

Fragment1.java

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    EditText ed;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container,false);

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ed = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        ed.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TimerPickerFragment newFragment = new TimerPickerFragment();
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "tag");

            }
        });

    }

    public void setEdittextvalue(String value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ed.setText(value);

    }



}
```

**TimerPickerFragment.java**

```
public class TimerPickerFragment extends DialogFragment
implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mCallback = (PickTime) activity;
    }

    public interface PickTime
    {
        public void returnTime(String value);

    }

    PickTime mCallback;
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user

        if(mCallback!=null)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(hourOfDay);
            sb.append(":");
            sb.append(minute);
            mCallback.returnTime(sb.toString());
        }
    }
}



}
```

Thanks !!

Comment: can you log the value in `setEdittextvalue` and check??

Comment: i used this statement  Logd("TimeValue",value.toString()); .... but i cant see anything in log window..... its empty ... should i need to enable any setting .... dont know why i can see log statements for other projects ,..... but not here

Comment: `newFragment.isVisible()` requires api level 11

Comment: but you should see the value in the log. then we can think about other errors. for now you can comment that line. but atleast should the log

Comment: i tried the same code it works for me.

Comment: you can comment that line and try to log the value

Comment: also should you not be using `getSupportFragmentManager` here  `newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "tag");` . i am pretty sure that you should atleast see the log value

Comment: but i need to use support fragment lib ... everywhere since i am using API-8?

Comment: yes you should use support library

Comment: Ok i made some progress .... in my main project(not this project) i am able to set the value(problem still remains about the log though) this individual project i can't set the value, both places i used same code .... can u show how to set 12 hr format in the other question