# Reading data selected in TimePicker called from a Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, listener, timepicker

I have a `Fragment` that has its own layout and has a **Choose Time** button along with a `TextView` beneath it. I am opening a `TimePickerFragment` from this `Fragment` when the user clicks this button.
Now when the user selects a time, and clicks done, I want to populate the `TextView` contained in the fragment. I am not sure how to do this.

All the materials/tutorials online invoke the `timepicker` from an Activity. I do (obviously) have a Parent Activity, but since this TimePicker is only being used in this Fragment, I would like to limit the scope as much as possible. 
So the flow is as follows:
`ParentActivity` > `Fragment (contains TextView and button)` > `DialogFragment (TimePicker)`

Here is my implementation:

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment  implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        int hour = 0; 
        int minute = 0;
        boolean is24Hour = false; 

        // ... Some code to read shared preference, get the correct time format, theme, etc.

        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), dialog_theme, this, hour, minute, is24Hour); //DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity())

    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {

        //TextView textView = (TextView) getView.findViewById(R.id.time_value); //NullPointerException! 
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time_value); //Also NullPointerException! 

        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
        textView.setText(TimeAndDate.getDisplayableTime(time));

        textView.clearFocus();

    }

}
```

Comment: To which layout does the textview belong to and the layout belongs to activity or DialogFragment?

Comment: It belongs to the Fragment which invokes the DialogFragment. I will update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It belongs to the Fragment which invokes the DialogFragment

`findViewById` looks for a view with the id in the current view hierarchy. The `TextView` is not a child of `TimerView`.

So you need to initialize `TextView` in Fragment not `DialogFragment`.

All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly. Use interface as a call back to the Activity and then communciate the time to the Fragment.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

DialogFragment --> ParentActivtiy --> Fragment

You can check the example @

[Simple timepicker for a fragment activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794305/simple-timepicker-for-a-fragment-activity)

Comment: I see. I knew why the error was occuring, but was not sure how to do it right. Trying your example now.

Comment: So if I have multiple fragments which can invoke TimePicker, each should be instantiated in the main Activity? (Or may be I can create a  parent Fragment for all those and instantiate just that?). But here, if I am replacing the EditFragment with some other fragment not related to timepicker, then I will have to hold the reference to that an as well in the Main Activity right?

Comment: @rgamber the design is left you to decide. yes you need to instantiate in MainActivity.

Comment: @rgamber Note: Fragments are attached to the Activity

Comment: agreed.  Yes, but how do I findout which fragment is currently active?

Comment: @rgamber check which fragment is attached to the activity. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isAdded()

Comment: Now I get the idea of whats happening. The callback is called at the right time and with right values. But somehow, `newFragment.isVisible()` always returns `false`, so the TextView is not updated.

Comment: @rgamber the link posted has a working example. Its for you to figure out why

Comment: @rgamber you are welcome. But if you still find difficulty you can post a new question

Comment: Sounds good. I got the basic case to work, but I am having 3 Fragments which can invoke the TimePicker. I am changing the design, but will post a new question incase I get stuck. Thanks again!